# 'The government will introduce new laws aimed at stopping domestic violence.'

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I have come across this  following sentence but I could not figure out the highlighted part of its structure.

> In the next session of parliament, the government will introduce new
>   laws **aimed** at stopping domestic violence.

For me it should be :

'In the next session of parliament, the government will introduce new laws (which are ) **aiming** at stopping domestic violence.'

I feel that there seems to be reduced relative clause after the word laws which is subject of it.On the other hand I think the new laws cannot 'aim at' by itself, is it 'a passive reduced relative clause' ,if there is something like that?

Comment: 'In the next session of parliament, the government will introduce new laws (which will be) aimed [targeted] at stopping domestic violence.'

Comment: Both forms of the verbal phrase modify *laws* with a metaphorical use of *aim*, indicating the **purpose** of the laws. The relative (which are) can be implied in both constructions. *Aiming* establishes a progressive view of the aim.

Comment: It's fine as written.  "Aimed at", in that context, means "with the intended purpose of".

Comment: Preferring fewer words, I suggest "In the next session of parliament, the government will introduce new laws to stop domestic violence." If you really must, I suppose you could add the word "designed" before the infinitive "to stop."

Comment: "cannot 'aim at' by itself" -- what makes us think so? "The laws are aimed at" = "The laws have their objective as" -- where is the problem?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's a NARQ.

Comment: More food for thought [here](http://www.proz.com/forum/translation_theory_and_practice/116300-difference_between_aim_at_%2Bing_and_aim_%2B_infinite.html) and [here](https://www.englishforums.com/English/SubtleDifferencesAimsAims/klhpk/post.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The original and your rewrite express different agents.

In the original somebody (presumably the government) *aims* the laws at a target, as you might *aim* a rifle; The clause expresses the **government**'s intention to stop domestic violence by means of the laws.

In your rewrite the laws are anthropomorphized, treated as themselves capable of *aiming at* a goal. The clause expresses the **laws**' intention; the government is merely the force which sets the laws into operation.