# Noun + Past Participle Usage

Tags: verbs, compound-adjectives, scientific-language

DCR(Dark Current Rate) represents the base noise level of a SPAD **caused** by parasitic avalanches happening in the dark due to thermal noise and band-to-band tunnelling effects.

I don't understand why the author wrote **caused** instead of writing **is caused** in the above sentence. Please explain how to use and form such kinds of sentences and what are they called?
Please explain it with some examples if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['The government will introduce new laws aimed at stopping domestic violence.'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227905/the-government-will-introduce-new-laws-aimed-at-stopping-domestic-violence) Though [Is 'the high shear stress induced can lead to ...' correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532210/is-induced-can-lead-correct) may help you more. Your example might well have used 'that is caused by' instead of 'caused by'; they have used what some label a _reduced relative clause_.

Comment: **Is caused** would be ungrammatical. But ***that*** **is caused** would work.